# Rails remote form parameter not being passed to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, parameters, actioncable

I have a form in my rails app where a user just enters a number and the form is then submitted with ajax. A new game is created in my gamescontroller if all the parameters are present. I have two hidden_field_tags whose parameters pass to the controller very nicely but the most important parameter, the one gotten from user input, doesn't seem to pass to the controller.

My form:

```
<%= form_for @game, :url => {:controller => "games", :action => "create" }, :html => { :role => 'form' }, remote: true, method: :post do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <%= f.text_field :user_stake, class: 'form-control' %>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <%= f.submit 'Go', :html => { :type => "button" }, class: "btn btn-default" %>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id  %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'jackpot_id', @jackpot.id  %>

<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
 before_action :game_params, only: [:create]

  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)
    if @game.save
      @jackpot = Jackpot.find(params[:jackpot_id])
      ActionCable.server.broadcast 'jackpot_channel',
                                        users: Jackpot.where(id: @jackpot.id),
                                        pot: @jackpot,
                                        user: User.find(@game.user_id),
                                        game: @game,
                                        stake: @game.user_stake.to_s
    else
      ActionCable.server.broadcast 'jackpot_channel',
                                        error: @game.errors.full_messages
    end
  end

  def new
    @game = Game.new
  end

  private
    def game_params
      params.permit(:user_stake, :user_id, :jackpot_id)
    end
```

No matter what is typed in the @game gets saved with a user_stake of 0.0, which I have set as the default in my migrations. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Any hint in the rails server at the moment to submit the form?

Comment: Remove `before_action :game_params, only: [:create]`. It does absolutely nothing except waste time/memory.

Comment: What is the DB column type?

Comment: @max it’s a decimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not nesting the inputs properly:

```
<%= form_for @game, html: { role: 'form' }, remote: true do |f| %>  
  <%= f.text_field :user_stake, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id  %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'jackpot_id', @jackpot.id  %> 
  # ..
<% end %>
```

This would give the following params hash:

```
{
   game: {
     user_stake: 1.2
   },
   user_id: 3,
   jackpot_id: 4
}
```

If you send that through the whitelist you get:

```
{
   user_id: 3,
   jackpot_id: 4
}
```

One solution is to simply nest the inputs:

```
<%= form_for @game, html: { role: 'form' }, remote: true do |f| %>  
  <%= f.text_field :user_stake, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id  %>
  <%= f.hidden_field_tag 'jackpot_id', @jackpot.id  %> 
  # ..
<% end %>
```

And whitelist them properly:

```
private
  def game_params
    params.require(:game)
          .permit(:user_stake, :user_id, :jackpot_id)
  end
```

But there is a huge warning flag here - **NEVER** pass the current user id through the params as it makes it really easy for a malicous user to hack with nothing but the web inspector. Instead use the value directly from the session.

You can't fake that except with the users password or by cracking the session encryption.

Also if a game belongs to a jackpot I would set it up as a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) and put the id in the path as this creates a RESTful structure that clearly shows that you are adding children to a parent resource - instead of hiding that vital information in the request body.

```
# routes.rb
resources :jackpots do
  resources :games, shallow: true
end
```

---

```
class GamesController
  before_action :set_jackpot, only: [:new, :create, :index]

  # GET /jackpots/:jackpot_id/games/new
  def new
    @game = @jackpot.games.new
  end

  # POST /jackpots/:jackpot_id/games
  def create
    @game = @jackpot.games.new(game_params) do |g|
      g.user = current_user
    end

    if @game.save
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  # GET /jackpots/:jackpot_id/games
  def index
    @games = @jackpot.games
  end

  private 

    def set_jackpot
      @jackpot = Jackpot.includes(:games)
                        .find(params[:jackpot_id])
    end

    def game_params
      params.require(:game).permit(:user_stake)
    end
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for [@jackpot, @game], remote: true, html: { role: 'Form' } do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <%= f.number_field :user_stake, class: 'form-control' %>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <%= f.submit 'Go', :html => { :type => "button" }, class: "btn btn-default" %>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Note how there are no hidden inputs required.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very comprehensive and helpful answer. I did what you suggested and everything seems to be working perfectly now. Just one question: I'm wondering whether I should keep the routes like you said to because Game doesn't belong to Jackpot, rather I have set up a many to many association where User has_many :jackpots, through => games. Should I keep the routes like you said or change them? Thanks

Comment: Well in that case you do have a belongs_to association between jackpot and game.

Comment: A game belongs to a jackpot and a jackpot has many games. So yeah it still makes sense to nest it.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to inspect your server logs to see what is being posted to your controller's create method.  I suspect the game Parameters are encapsulated in a `game` hash.  To access it, I'd recommend changing `game_params` to require game:

```
def game_params
  params.require(:game).permit(:user_stake, :user_id, :jackpot_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On submission of the form I see this in the logs: INSERT INTO "games" ("user_id", "jackpot_id", "created_at", "updated_at") . The user_stake isn't present. Just to be clear I'm trying to pass user_stake not game. Game is my model

Comment: Yes...but your game_params may be filtering out your parameters.  I would recommend inspecting the results of `game_params` and of `params`.  This  will help you diagnose where the data is being filtered out.  Placing [byebug](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-byebug-gem) at the top of your `create` method could help you inspect these variables.